# How create a custom UIView that contains multiple images laid side by side

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, drawrect

I am creating a simple program that takes an array of image paths and draws them side by side in a CustomUIView. Does anyone know how I might proceed? I am stuck with what should go instead of `<#statements#>` in the code below (which is my whole class so far).

```
#import "EFGUICatsView.h"

@implementation EFGUICatsView


-(void)setCatsPathsArray:(NSArray *)catsPathsArray
{
    _catsPathsArray=catsPathsArray;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];//redraw image
}



// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *cat=nil;
    for (NSString * imagePath in self.catsPathsArray) {
        cat = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
        if (cat) {
            <#statements#>
        }
    }
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Comment: Look at the "Drawing Images" tasks section of the `UIImage` docs.

Comment: @rmaddy whatever I am supposed to get from the docs, I am not getting it. I am looking at a few samples and the best I can gather so far is to use a tableView. But I think there has to be a simpler way that does not include more view hierarchies.

Comment: Use the `UIImage drawInRect:` to draw each image.

Comment: @rmaddy, I am desperate for help. So I am glad that someone is responding to my post, but really you have to know that your statements are not offering any help. Maybe you have been coding for iOS for so long you forgot what it means to get stuck on the obvious things. On the bright side, since you seem to be an expert, a little effort on your part may be all I need. So thanks if you decide to give me a little bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply draw each image:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *cat=nil;
    for (NSString * imagePath in self.catsPathsArray) {
        cat = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
        if (cat) {
            // Calculate the x and y values based on the needs of your layout
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(someX, someY, cat.size.width, cat.size.height);
            [cat drawInRect:rect];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I am troubleshooting some related errors in the code so I can't report back yet. `self.catsPathsArray` is mysteriously empty in `drawRect` although logging reveals that the array is set in `-(void)setCatsPathsArray:(NSArray *)catsPathsArray`. My array property is set to `@property(copy,nonatomic)`

Comment: `drawRect:` may be called numerous times including before the `catsPathsArray` property is set.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But I imagine at some point it would call when there is data in the array since I am calling `[self setNeedsDisplay]` on the setter. But per the loggings, `drawRect` is only called once and that's apparently before the data is set.

Comment: Calling `setNeedsDisplay` should result in `drawRect` being called eventually. If not then there is some other issue.

Comment: After fixing the empty array problem, the images were still not showing. So to get them to show I had to define a `UIBezierPath` and clip to it with `addClip`.